# How do I add 2 players and give them cards ? [Python]

Tags: python

i'm new to OOP and I've been stuck in writing this for the past hour. I just don't understand how to assign the deck I created to 2 players !

## Classes

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, faceNum, suitNum):
        self.faceNum = faceNum
        self.suitNum = suitNum

    def getCardName(self):
          nameSuit = ['Ace','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','Jack','Queen','King']
          nameFace = ['Coeur','Pique','Carreau','Trèfle']
          return "%s of %s" % (nameFace[self.faceNum], nameSuit[self.suitNum])

    def __str__(self):
        carte_print1 = str(self.faceNum)
        carte_print2 = str(self.suitNum)
        return carte_print1 +('-')+ carte_print2

class Player:
    def __init__(self,ID,Card):
        self.PlayerID = ID
        self.CardForPlayer = Card
```

## Main code

```
import random

playerA = list()
playerB = list()
deck = list()

def deck():
    deck = []
    for suitNum in range(13):
    for faceNum in range(4):
        deck.append(Card(faceNum, suitNum))
    return deck

deck = deck()
random.shuffle(deck)
for card in deck:
    print(card.getCardName())
```

Now I just need to give 2 player an equal amount of cards how do I do this ?!

Answer (score 1):

So there should be an attribute in the `Player` class with the name like `deck`. Modify your `Player` class like this.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self,ID,deck):
        self.PlayerID = ID
        self.deck = deck # this will hold a list of Card objects
```

Now in your main code, at the end of what you've written, add the following lines.

```
player1 = Player(1, deck())
player2 = Player(2, deck())
```

Comment: Ok, makes sense. And from there how exactly can I assign them the 52 cards equally ?

Comment: Many ways. Perhaps add  a 'deal' method to the deck that accepts 2 players (or maybe a list of players for bigger games?). Also, call me a purist, but would the cards a player holds be considered their 'hand'?

Comment: @iLearnn You might want to fix the indent on the __init__ method for posterity.

Comment: @iLearnn You are already assigning them 13 cards from each of the 4 suits (52 cards) by calling the `deck()` method. Notice that we have `deck()` with parenthesis in the `player1` and `player2` declarations (that executes that `deck()` method.

Comment: @bourbaki4481472 I did that but then when I print the player it says <Player object at 0x03EF3ED0>. How do I access that memory ?

Comment: @iLearnn You would need to overwrite the default method that turns a Java object into a string. I suggest you ask a separate question about that.

Comment: @iLearnn if my answer helped you, considering accepting this answer.